# Push-n and pull-n bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Have bootstrap `push-n` and `pull-n` how in foundation? Or planned it do in future or how i can do custom `push-n` and `pull-n` in boostrap?
Thanks!

Comment: Scroll down to Column Ordering to see how to Push and Pull in Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do have these classes, they are called `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*`

[Link to getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)